# remove global messages not working

Tags: blocks

I need to remove global messages. I did put following to local.xml

```
<remove name="global_messages" />
<remove name="messages" />
```

but messages still appear. I also tried to comment out following lines in page.xml

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

which also did not work. Notice messages still appear. Where are the messages still coming from if commented out in page.xml?
and Yes, I did flush Magento cash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because...
For example in the product view page this template is rendered: `catalog/product/view.phtml`.
This template contains at the top this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

And `$this->getMessagesBlock()` is defined in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and it looks like this:

```
    public function getMessagesBlock()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_messagesBlock)) {
            return $this->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock();
        }
        return $this->_messagesBlock;
    }
```

This means that it calls: `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::getMessagesBlock();`

This last method is

```
    public function getMessagesBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getBlock('messages');
        if ($block) {
            return $block;
        }
        return $this->createBlock('core/messages', 'messages');
    }
```

This means that if a block with the name 'messages' is not found in the layout is created and returned.

I see 2 possible solutions here:

1. Edit all the template files and remove `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>`. But I wouldn't take this road. It's to much time consuming and you might miss something.
2. Override "magento style" the method: `Mage_Core_Block_Messages::getGroupedHtml()` to return an empty string.

First I thought of overriding `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::getMessagesBlock()` to return nothing if the block is not in layout, but you will get errors when calling `->getGroupedHtml()` on a non object.

but you can try overriding `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::getMessagesBlock()` to return a simple `core/template` block that does not have a method `getGroupedHtml()` method and  will return null when called. (this would be the third solution.)

Comment: tnx! this make sense now:) but could you be more specific about the 'magento style' ?

Comment: By "Magento style" I mean that you shouldn't modify the core or copy the file in the local folder. This is a good example on how to override stuff: http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/ . I hope is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add in `XML` unused block like

```
<block type="core/messages" name="grab_messages" />
```

before old blocks. Because first exemplar of `core/messages` block grab all messages and clear messages from session.